# Job or work history. How correct?

Tags: word-choice

I have a problem choosing the right combination of words for naming a variable in my program.

I have to choose among the following values:

1. job history
2. work history

Which is correct? This variable describes the companies in which a person has worked and his work history.

Comment: Does it actually matter?  Your average variable name isn't seen to the end user, so call it pumpkinPie for all you like.  If you mean what should you display to the user, @bib is a great option.  See also http://ux.stackexchange.com for these sort of user-interface questions.

Comment: Thanks for link. Yes, this variable for internal use only, but the name of this variable have matter. Right name == comfortable development  project in team.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Naming, including naming programming variables/classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you should consider *employment history*?

Comment: I used this option before, but thought that I was wrong. I was doing right, thanks!

Comment: All three are correct, and *work history* actually appears most frequently in the [Google database of publications](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=job+history%2Cwork+history%2Cemployment+history&year_start=1975&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) followed by *employment history*, then *job history*. However *employment* is probably the most formal term.

Comment: @bib well, it also applies best in this specific circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

Work History   is the total number of various jobs you have held.

Job History    is  the pertinent history applicable the job you are
applying for

Comment: Can you substantiate that? That's not how I would understand the terms.